# In Django, how can I manually create users for my project?

Tags: django

I would like to process all of my users manually rather than having an automated registration process.  I have looked at the documentation and there is a command line facility for creating a super user.  Can I create ordinary users from the command line or some equivalent manual process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create user in django `create_user()` helper function that comes with Django. You can refer this [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#creating-users) for more information which was available in Django Documentation.

Another way can be dumping all the user lists directly in the database. Let say if you use MySQL Database, you can simply dump the data from CSV format into MySQL Database.